# Check if an element is present in a vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

I have a generic class Basic:

```
class Basic
{
public: 
    Basic(string name): name(name){}
    string Name() {return name;}
private:
    string name;
};

class Basic2: public Basic
{
public: 
    Basic(string name, int value): Basic(name),value(value){}
    string Name() {return name;}
private:
    string name;
    int value;
};
class Basic3: public Basic
{
public: 
    Basic(string name, string value2): Basic(name),value2(value2){}
    string Name() {return name;}
private:
    string name;
    string value2;
};
```

Three other class inherit from Basic but have different features (let's call them Basic1,Basic2,Basic3).
I have a vector of basic: `vector<Basic*> v`

I know how to insert element inside the vector. But I would like to check if the element is present and insert it only if it is not. I assume that I cannot compare different types like Basic1 and Basic2 with == ? What would be the way to check if the element I want to insert is present in the vector? `

Comment: Use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), specifying the "equality" criteria (which you have not laid out in your question.)

Comment: and don't use a vector<Basic*>. Use a vector<unique_ptr<Basic>> or vector<shared_ptr<Basic>>.

Comment: @RichardHodges: And how do you know this vector has owning semantics?

Comment: Why shouldn't I use vector<Basic*>?

Comment: [Because pointers should not "own" resources.](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf). That said, are you looking for a way to find an element who's `Name()` method matches a prospect search string?

Comment: I want to find an element which is exactly the same as the one I want to insert: names are equal, and other attributs are equal.

Comment: @rusol if that is the case, the linked duplicate prospect is likely a decent match for what you're trying, though it may take a little massaging to tailor-fit to your specific needs. One way or another your elements need the fulfill the concept of "identity" to be able to compare against another, be that via a slurry of virtual method return comparisons or something else. Unrelated: learn what a `const` reference is good for.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am sure you understand perfectly well the issues surrounding the storage of pointers in an owning vector. Is it likely that they are merely references to another container that really owns the strings? No. The OP's level of demonstrated competence supports my position. I am doing him a favour by prompting him to think in the right. As should you. And you know it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a given `Base` *instance* already exists, you can use `std::find()` to look for the `Base*` pointer (and yes, this works with descendants):

```
Base *b = ...;
if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), b) == v.end())
    v.push_back(b);
```

If you want to check if a given `Base` *content* already exists, you can use `std::find_if()` instead:

```
struct MatchesBase
{
    Base *_b;
    MatchesBase(Base *b) : _b(b) {}
    bool operator()(const Base *b) const
    {
        // compare b to _b as needed...
        // return true if matches, else false
    }
};

Base *b = ...;
if (std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesBase(b)) == v.end())
    v.push_back(b);
```

Comment: But it means I have to do that for every methods that inherit from Base. And what if I overload the operator ==,  is the types are different I return false otherwise I make a true comparison between the elements?

Answer (score -2):

You can check object typeid

```
typeid(NewObject) == typeid(myVector[i])
```

See this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/operator==/).

Comment: -1 this is not the right answer and does not address the question being asked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "I assume that I cannot compare different types like Basic1 and Basic2 with == ?" is part of the question, no? I do not think I'm completely wrong in saying that one of the possible interpretations of the questions are just that: Can I add only one instance per type?

Comment: If you want to check if a given instance of a particular class type is present, one would typically use `dynamic_cast` instead of `typeid`, especially if you also need to access class-specific members.